# How to set an image's date and time with timezone with exiftool?

Tags: exiftool

[ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is a powerful tool for modifying meta data on images.  What is the simple command line to specify the date and time for an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is the fact that the EXIF standard separates the date/time (`EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`) and the time zone (`EXIF:OffsetTimeOriginal`) into different tags.  The subseconds (`EXIF:SubSecTimeOriginal`) are also located in a different tag.

Luckily, exiftool gives you a shortcut to write all three locations in a single command.  You would use

```
exiftool -SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2022:12:12 12:00:00.24-08:00" /path/to/files/
```

This will write 2022:12:12 12:00:00 to the `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`, 24 to the `EXIF:SubSecTimeOriginal`, and -08:00 `EXIF:OffsetTimeOriginal` at the same time.

Also of note are the `SubSecCreateDate` and `SubSecModifyDate` tags.

`SubSecCreateDate` writes to the `EXIF:CreateDate` (called `DateTimeDigitized` by the EXIF spec), `EXIF:SubSecTimeDigitized`, and the `EXIF:OffsetTimeDigitized` tags.  `SubSecModifyDate` writes to the `EXIF:ModifyDate` (called `DateTime` by the EXIF spec), `EXIF:SubSecTime`,
and the `EXIF:OffsetTime` tags.

There is also the XMP standard, which is much more flexible.  It can either be embedded in the file or as an XMP sidecar.  The XMP standard allows for all the data in a single tag.  The command for writing to an XMP tag would be similar

```
exiftool -XMP:DateTimeOriginal="2022:12:12 12:00:00.24-08:00" /path/to/files/
```

Additional tags for XMP would be `XMP:CreateDate` and `XMP:ModifyDate`

One final thing to take note of for the XMP time stamps is that the [Exif 2.32 metadata for XMP standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20180921145139if_/http://www.cipa.jp:80/std/documents/e/DC-010-2017_E.pdf) uses `XMP:DateTimeOriginal` as the corresponding tag for `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`, while the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard 2022.1](https://iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata#date-created) uses the `XMP:DateCreated` as the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html) and [Forums](https://exiftool.org/forum) have many details, but a simple answer is

```
exiftool -datetimeoriginal="2022:10:23 17:40.00" <filename>
```

For October 23rd, 2022, 5:40pm.  However, this **does not set timezone**.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully clarifying the mud, .

### How to set an image's date, time and timezone using ExifTool

One issue to overcome is the fact that the EXIF standard has individual tags for

date/time  (EXIF:DateTimeOriginal)
subseconds (EXIF:SubSecTimeOriginal)
time zone  (EXIF:OffsetTimeOriginal)

Luckily, exiftool gives you a shortcut to write to all three locations in a single command.

You would use the SubSecDateTimeOriginal tag, as in ...

exiftool -SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2022:12:12 12:00:00.24-08:00" /path/to/files/

This will write the following data to their respective tags.

2022:12:12 12:00:00 → EXIF:DateTimeOriginal
24                  → EXIF:SubSecTimeOriginal
-08:00              → EXIF:OffsetTimeOriginal

Notice above, that SubSecDateTimeOriginal is NOT prepended with the Group name,
-EXIF:

Also of note are the SubSecCreateDate and SubSecModifyDate tags.

SubSecCreateDate writes to the following three tags.

EXIF:CreateDate            ← called DateTimeDigitized by the EXIF spec.
EXIF:SubSecTimeDigitized
EXIF:OffsetTimeDigitized

SubSecModifyDate writes to the following three tags.

EXIF:ModifyDate            ← called DateTime by the EXIF spec.
EXIF:SubSecTime
EXIF:OffsetTime

There is also the XMP standard, which (as well as explicitly stating the metadata commands on the command-line), has a dedicated file, a so-called 'XMP sidecar' file, from which the commands can be read. Although not promoted 'up-front', Exiftool also has this capability.

The command for writing to an XMP tag is similar to that of writing to an EXIF tag, in that the date/time, subseconds and timezone can all be written using the single tag DateTimeOriginal

exiftool -XMP:DateTimeOriginal="2022:12:12 12:00:00.24-08:00" /path/to/files/

Notice here, that DateTimeOriginal is prepended with the Group name, -XMP:
Additional tags for using with XMP would be XMP:CreateDate and XMP:ModifyDate

One final thing that you should be aware of when writing XMP time-stamps, is that, while EXIF:DateTimeOriginal is the date and time that the original image was shot/taken, differing standards that employ XMP will utilise their own tags for this purpose, specifically ...

Exif 2.32 metadata for XMP standard will use
XMP:DateTimeOriginal

### IPTC Photo Metadata Standard 2022.1 will use
XMP:DateCreated

Excluding the timezone, a simpler command to just set the date & time for an image to October 23rd, 2022 at 5:40pm, would be ...

exiftool -datetimeoriginal="2022:10:23 17:40.00"

### In this example, notice that 'datetimeoriginal' is not prepended with any Group name.

Group Priorities
ExifTool prioritises the following types of meta information when writing:

1. EXIF, 2) IPTC, 3) XMP

Many tag names are valid for more than one of these groups. If a group name is not specified when writing information, then the information is added only to the highest priority group for which the tag name is valid, (however, the information is updated in all groups where the tag already existed).
The priority of the groups is given by the list above.

Specifically, this means that new information is added preferentially to the EXIF group, or to the IPTC group if no corresponding EXIF tag exists, or finally to the XMP group.

Alternatively, information may be written to a specific group only, bypassing these priorities, by providing a group name for the tag.